# How to access json file stored under web-app inside servlet & jsp?

Tags: json, jsp, servlets

I have my json file that I am going to place under web-app folder. This file is not generated on the fly but created manually. Hence want to store under web-app. I need to render the page in jsp/servlet using this json file. How to get access to json file in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a servlet and serve the file from there to the clients. You can load it with

```
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/file.json");
```

and write it directly to your OutputStream.

Comment: Can I put the json file outside web-inf but inside web-app and do the same? Cause I need this file at client side(in jquery) also.

Comment: @Prakash Yes, it should be possible. If it does not work check your build, everything inside your war can be loaded.